# CREATE DATABASE permission denied in database 'master' error despite using MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2012

I’m having a very strange issue when deploying an mvc 4 application to my web server. I’ve used MySQL for the whole project but after loading up the project on another server I’m getting the error message: “[SqlException (0x80131904):  CREATE DATABASE permission denied in database 'master'.” which seems to be an MS SQL error, even though I'm not even using it!

When I deploy my project locally as an IIS site, it works absolutely fine. There’s no MS SQL connection string in my web.config, I’ve open every individual file in my project to see if there’s anything references MS SQL, but to no avail (it's safe to say it's driving my crazy).

Has anyone had this issue before? Is there perhaps some sort of remnants in an empty MVC 4 Web Application that I should look for?

Comment: "There’s no SQL connection string in my web.config"??? Seriously?? You hard code the connection string inside every file??? That sounds like a bad idea.

Comment: There's a connection string for MySQL not MS SQL

Comment: Just because a user can log into a database (your connection string credentials), it doesn't mean the user has the authority to 'create' a database. It could be you have a mis-match. Also, not sure of this, but your SqlException may be an ADO sqlexception and not an actual MS SQL Server error. Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

For anyone else who has the same issue, I found that removing the Entity Framework fixed it; To remove it, I followed this answer: [Is there a way to remove the default dependency on Entity Framework within MVC 4?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15711298/is-there-a-way-to-remove-the-default-dependency-on-entity-framework-within-mvc-4/15712400#15712400)